# MongoDB Get All Records for Grouped Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, grouping

I have tried to setup a simple gist to explain my problem and what I want [here](https://gist.github.com/53039e8b3f209759d091).

It definitely does not replicate my exact document structure (which is quite different), but will help you to understand my problem easily.

Update:

Gist was deleted accidentally so updating the question with the problem:

Let's say I have this structure

```
    _id  name  birthdate
    ...  john  10 aug
    ...  doe   11 aug
    ...  foo   11 aug
    ...  bar   12 aug
    ...  baz   12 aug
    ...  bak   12 aug
    ...  buzz  13 aug
```

I want to find all documents that share the same birthdate, so my resultset would be there:

```
    _id  name  birthdate
    ...  doe   11 aug
    ...  foo   11 aug
    ...  bar   12 aug
    ...  baz   12 aug
    ...  bak   12 aug
```

I would also somehow like to get the count() of the date-shared records against each document. so, something like this

```
    _id  name  birthdate  count
    ...  doe   11 aug     2
    ...  foo   11 aug     2
    ...  bar   12 aug     3
    ...  baz   12 aug     3
    ...  bak   12 aug     3
```

Till now all I have tried is mapReduce but with that I could only get:

```
    _id     value
    11 aug  {count: 2}
    12 aug  {count: 3}
```

Comment: Erm: "The Gist you were looking for has been deleted. Sorry about that!".  You should include a description of the problem in your question, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your result would be easier to achieve using the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2.

The example below is using the MongoDB shell, but a similar approach will work from Mongoid.

Assuming data set up with:

```
db.users.insert({'name': 'john', 'birthdate':'10 aug'});
db.users.insert({'name': 'doe',  'birthdate':'11 aug'});
db.users.insert({'name': 'foo',  'birthdate':'11 aug'});
db.users.insert({'name': 'bar',  'birthdate':'12 aug'});
db.users.insert({'name': 'baz',  'birthdate':'12 aug'});
db.users.insert({'name': 'bak',  'birthdate':'12 aug'});
db.users.insert({'name': 'buzz', 'birthdate':'13 aug'});
```

Here is a commented example of the aggregate command:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    // Group and count documents by same birthdate
    { $group: {
        '_id' : '$birthdate',
        'name': { $addToSet: '$name' },
        'count': { $sum: 1 },
    }},

    // Only match documents with at least one duplicate
    { $match : {
        'count' : { $gt: 1 }
    }},

    // Unwind the grouped documents so there is one per name
    { $unwind : '$name' },

    // Sort results by _id and name
    { $sort : {
        '_id': 1,
        'name': 1,
    }}
)
```

.. and the results:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "11 aug",
            "name" : "doe",
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : "11 aug",
            "name" : "foo",
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : "12 aug",
            "name" : "bak",
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : "12 aug",
            "name" : "bar",
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : "12 aug",
            "name" : "baz",
            "count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Note: Mongoid will have a "helper" for the Aggregation Framework added soon .. it's already in the new Moped driver: [issue 2329](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2329).  You can also access the `aggregate` command directly.  For example, see the [moped pull request](https://github.com/rodrigosaito/moped/commit/d3ba541e9fb00eab144b38e94910ca07f21e4447) which implements the aggregate support :).